# Web Platform Installer : 0MB -- Azure SDK 2.5.1 install issues

Tags: azure-sdk-.net, web-platform-installer

Using Visual Studio 2013 Professional, using the web platform installer I select Microsoft Azure SDK for .NET (VS 2013) - 2.5.1.

I add and click install.

The next screen tells me what it's installing, showing 0MB in terms of size.

![enter image description here][1]

The operation finishes, however I create the new project I see the sdk listed with 0MB for file size.

If I install and let it finish, when I go back to the web platform installer, it indicated 2.5.1 sdk was not installed.

I tried doing a manual install from here which didn't work: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/archive-net-downloads/

Additionally, all other items I'm trying to install through web platform installer show 0 MB.

Comment: Any luck with resolving this? I'm also facing this on Windows 10 Preview and Visual Studio 2015